# How to set background color for TextFormField Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textformfield

This is the following code where I tried setting TextFormField Widget Color.
I tried changing the color of the Container Widget and the Card Widget, but I couldn't alter the color of the TextFormField Widget in particular.

```
child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Card(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(children: [
    Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 50, 30, 20),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                        ),
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.email,
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                        labelText: "Email",
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                                      ),
        

                        ),
```

Comment: Use `fillColor: Colors.orange` and `filled: true` inside your `InputDecoration()`.

Answer (score 22):

Use fillColor and filled attributes of InputDecoration

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                                filled: true,

          labelText: "Resevior Name",
          fillColor: Colors.black,
          
        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried a few different approaches to changing the color of the TextFormField Widget. Finally, I discovered how to change the background color of the TextFormField Widget.

Set the filled property of the TextFormField Widget to true and the fillColor property to the desired color.
i.e.,

```
fillColor: Colors.white,
filled: true,
```

**Code**

```
child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Card(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(children: [
    Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 50, 30, 20),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                                          filled: true,
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                        ),
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.email,
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                        labelText: "Email",
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                                      ),
        

                        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "title",
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true, // dont forget this line
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```